# Sitemap appearance is not proper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a sitemap in my project i did some changes and then the sitemap lost its appearance and its appearing like this.

[image: Unexpected]

And what I have in another site is like this..

[image: Expected]

Both of them are using the same style sheet. Even I tried copying from one to another but when i paste it then it will loose its design color. I don't know what's wrong. I checked the config file and other project properties but doesn't seems like working.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and .Net framework 4.0 in both cases

Code for the Menu control(Which is same in both):

CSS : 
    /* TAB MENU
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #F87431;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #F87431;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I assume no version control here?

Comment: Double check you are importing your CSS file in both pages

Comment: "Inspect element" using a browser such as Google Chrome and see which styles are not being applied.

Comment: Come on, what's wrong in the question for down vote?

Comment: Well I haven't downvoted but how do you expect anyone to be able to give you an answer - you have not given us anything to go on. Show the ASPX/CSS, what changes have you made? What have you tried? (i.e look at the comments above)

Comment: These screenshots are from the VS designer - what do the pages really look like in the browser?

Comment: @HansKesting : They look the same in the browser also.. I'm not a newbie for ASP but in this case i'm out of thoughts..

Comment: have you applied the Menu css class ?

Comment: Yes, I have applied the css.. Wonder is that if i copy the menu from the other site and paste it in my site, it looses the format and becomes plain text(like in pic 1)

Comment: What do you see when you view the generated source? Your CSS targets a list but old versions of .NET render the menu as a table - see if you have this setting somewhere in your Web.Config controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion=3.5 and remove if it exists

Comment: @KevinMain : You are the man...!! You made my day, wasted 4 hours on this.. Thanks.. Plz paste this as an answer. Thanks a lot by the way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS targets a list but old versions of .NET render the menu as a table - see if you have this setting somewhere in your Web.Config

```
controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion=3.5
```

This tells .NET to render controls the old way via tables so your CSS will not be applied - remove that and it should render as UL/LI tags and your styles will now work.